# How to provide custom list of selectable dates to the calendar in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I want to supply the list of dates to the calendar such that the selected dates are shown and the other dates are greyed out or not selectable in the calendar.

Sending a list of dates to the calendar in such a way that when user opens the calendar to select a date, only the dates from the list is visible and the other dates are greyed out.

Answer (score 0):

use https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars#date-marking, and after give a obj to markedDates and set disabled to true

Comment: I need a pop up calendar and the one suggested by you is a open calendar. Is there an alternative way for it ?